# Bootstrap 3: vertical alignment of inline radios

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When creating inline radios in a `form-horizontal`, is there any way to vertically align the radio buttons? fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bffjJ/) - note that button 'EF' is below button 'B', but is offset to the right - I'd like it to be directly below 'B'. I can mess around with padding but I'd rather use the grid if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bffjJ/1/)

The issue here is that you are effectively placing two columns of content within a single Bootrap column (`col-sm-4`), you either want to split the radio buttons into separate columns, or apply a set width to them so it is consistent across rows.
Try adding:

```
label{
    width:46%;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the width, which works well when applied to the label with the `radio-inline` class. I don't think there's any way to split the buttons into separate columns when using `form-horizontal`, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
    Option one
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
    option two
  </label>
</div>
```

Bootply [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bffjJ/2/)

Comment: Your suggestion for aligning two inline radios is to give up and make one of them un-inlined, but it's upvoted anyway?